# PostgreSQL not showing full table and table data in dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database with DBeaver. It is successfully connected, but I get an empty display for the table data. However, on another PC it is showing all the data. You can see that in the image below. How can I fix it?

All the tables and the data should come.

[image: DBeaver showing the table as empty]

Comment: Try with a different client (for example `psql`) on the same machine and see if you can see the table data there. Also, what happens in DBeaver if you start a query window and manually run `SELECT * FROM "Users"`?

Comment: I also checked the data after running psql command there but still data is not showing.can you provide me more context of this.Why it is happening?

Comment: I don't follow. Do you get an empty result if you query the table with `psql`?

Comment: yes the data is empty in table after running the psql command

Comment: Then the table is empty. There are two possible explanations: 1) you and the other PC are connecting to different databases, and one of them has an empty table 2) the other PC populated the table in a transaction and never committed. Then no other database session can see the data.